# The download folder is empty when the icloud is showing 'initializing...' on Windows

Tags: icloud, windows

I am trying to download a copy of my icloud pictures to a Windows PC.

Prior to this I have set the 'Download' folder to a different location (on a D: drive which has more space)

[image]

But so far the folder is empty

[image]

How long does it take for the photo to start to appear?

I am hesitate to try 'Download photos' button because last time I tried, it created a bunch of `<Folder name> (2)` folders (duplicate folders) and put a lot of photo in them. I can only stop it after signing out.